# Lagrange Interpolation Polynomial Code for coefficients

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

Can someone help me with developing a simple MATLAB code that inputs the n datasets $ \lbrace x_i : i=0,...,n \rbrace$ and $ \lbrace f^i : i=0,...,n \rbrace$ and produces the coefficients $ \lbrace c_i : i=0,...,n \rbrace$ of the Lagrange Polynomials?

I have an understanding of how to achieve the polynomial itself, but extracting each coefficients I am new to. Any help would be great :)

Thanks :)

Comment: For one way of doing this calculation (via C rather than MATLAB), see [this recent answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8250/819) on crypto.SE.  It uses subroutines/function-calls to a finite-field arithmetic package, but just replace these with ordinary arithmetic operations.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13151-lagrange-interpolator-polynomial/content/lagrangepoly/html/demo_lagrangepoly.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find coefficients of Lagrange interpolation polynomial relatively easy if you use a matrix form of Lagrange interpolation presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation" (you may check for concrete example in "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation"). General formula looks as follows
$$
f(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & f_0       & f_1       & \cdots & f_n       \\
        x^n     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Using Laplace expansion along the first column you can get expressions for coefficients at $x^i$.

**CODE**

I'm afraid, I don't know Matlab good enough to provide you with appropriate code, but I worked with Python a little bit, maybe the following can help (sorry for bad codestyle -- I'm mathematician, not programmer)

```
import numpy as np
# input
x = [0, 2, 4, 5]  # <- x's
y = [2, 5, 7, 7]  # <- y's
# calculating coefficients
M = [[_x**i*(-1)**(i*len(x)) for _x in x] for i in range(len(x))]
C = [np.linalg.det((M+[y]+M)[d:d+len(x)]) for d in range(len(x)+1)]
C = (C / C[0] * (-1)**(len(x)+1) )[1:]
# polynomial lambda-function
poly = lambda _x: sum([C[i] * _x**i for i in range(len(x))])
# output and tests
print("Coefficients:\n", C)
print("TESTING:")
for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
    result = "[OK]" if np.allclose(_y, poly(_x)) else "[ERROR]"
    print(_x, " mapped to: ", poly(_x), " ; expected: ", _y, result)
```

This code calculates coefficients of the Lagrange interpolation polynomial, prints them, and tests that given x's are mapped into expected y's. You can test this code with [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb), so you don't have to install anything. Probably, you can translate it to Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

```
function a = coefPolinomLagrange (x, y)
n = length(x);
M = [];
for i=1:n
    M = [M; x.^(i-1)'];
end

denom = M;
det_denom = det(denom);

Mcirc = [M;y';M(1:end-1,:)];

for i=1:n
    numer = Mcirc(i+1:i+n,:);
    a(i) = (-1)^(n-i) * det(numer) / det_denom;
end
a = fliplr(a);
end
```